# Обмен данными между сервером и клиентом php ajax

Tags: ajax, php

В интернет магазине, есть поиск по товарам.

При поиске на сервер отправляется, запрос, и возвращается XML, после я через js беру данные и вывожу в список ul.

Или может переделать, что бы на сервере создавался список ul с товарами и просто возвращался обычный текст, и выводился.

Что лучше и быстрее будет работать?

Answer (score 2):

Быстрее и проще будет отправлять с  сервера структуру данных в формате JSON.  И вот почему:

- во-1, не нужен парсер для обработки
     данных, JSON нативно превращается в
     переменную javascript;
- во-2,    структура данных в большинстве
     случаев компактнее хтмл-кода;
- во-3,   все задачи отображения рекомендуется
     выполнять на клиенте для снижения
     нагрузки на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо, но а по-поводу надежности и безопасности?

Comment: пардон, но это уже следующий вопрос..

Comment: @vasyavasya, а какие угрозы надежности и безопасности вы видите?